# WLST disconnect command issue

Tags: python, weblogic, wlst

I had ran `wlst.cmd` in my local system after I ran my Weblogic Admin Instance. But as WLST is stateful, I am getting connected to my IT env which is my Integration Testing environment (some UNIX machine for my project). I tried `disconnect()` to goto offline mode, however it is failed.

```
wls:/beaProjDir/serverConfig> disconnect()

You will need to be connected to a running server to execute this command
```

Please help to go offline mode in WLST. As I need to get some work done in my local system.

Comment: what do you mean by going offline modein wlst? you need to be connected to a running server for wlst to work.

Comment: By default WLST opens up in offline. And I came to know it is stateful. So it connected to some other server instance as it was last session. Now to come back to offline mode I tried executing `disconnect()` I had this issue. But still as you anticipate I could connect to other server, I mean connection hops to the one I am connecting to. But I am still curious that why did this `disconnect()` didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to getting out of WLST Shell ctrl+D. Which is similar to exiting from any other shell.